# How to make a dropdown value is selected during the page load based on the values fetched from DB in .net core?

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, ajax, asp.net-core

I have fixed dropdown values in the .cshtml file.
`**

Yes     
 No
 Ask Me` like this..
I'm saving these values into the DB and during the page load I'm fetching the values and assigning into the Model properties. But while I'm trying to bind the property value into the control(No) it's throwing an error says**:RZ1031: The tag helper 'option' must not have C# in the element's attribute declaration area.**. How to resolve this?
if it's possible give me the solution in `jquery `as well
I tried to bind the assigned Model values into the control. And it's throwing an error 'RZ1031: The tag helper 'option' must not have C# in the element's attribute declaration area.'

Answer (score 0):

According to your description, if you want to know how to use jquery to set the select value, I suggest you could refer to below example codes.

Since you don't have any codes, I just create a simple one.

Controller:

```
    public IActionResult Index()
    {

        //I directly new the model instead of query it from the database

        var vm = new MyViewModel { Id=1, SelectedValue = "Ask Me" }  ;


        return View(vm);
    }
```

Model:

```
public class MyViewModel
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string SelectedValue { get; set; }
}
```

View:

```
<select id="dropdownId" class="form-control">
    <option value="Yes">Yes</option>
    <option value="No">No</option>
    <option value="Ask Me">Ask Me</option>
</select>

@section Scripts{

    <script>
        $(document).ready(function () {

            var fetchedValue = "@Model.SelectedValue";

            // Set the selected option based on the fetched value
            $("#dropdownId").val(fetchedValue);
        });

    </script>
  

}
```

Result:

[image]